# Windows 7 WannaCrypt Patch/Update

Tags: windows-7, wannacrypt

Running Windows 7 Professional. It appears that the proper patch/update for me to protect against the wannacrypt virus is KB4012215.

I reviewed my Windows Update history and see that I tried to install that update on 3/18/17 but the installation "failed."

I right-clicked on it and the Error Code is 80070020.

Questions:

1. Is KB4012215 the proper update to guard against wannacrypt?
2. If not, please tell me the proper update and where and how to download and install it.
3. If so, please tell me where and how to download and install it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

> Is KB4012215 the proper update to guard against WannaCrypt?

It is indeed the correct patch

> - March, 2017 Security Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows 7 (KB4012215)
> - March, 2017 Security Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB4012215)
> - March, 2017 Security Only Quality Update for Windows 7 (KB4012212)
> - March, 2017 Security Only Quality Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB4012212)

[Patches That Fix the Vulnerability For MS17-010](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sudheesn/2017/05/17/patches-that-fix-the-vulnerability-for-ms17-010/)

> Please tell me where and how to download and install it.

You can download the patch [here](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4012215)

April 2017 Quality Rollup also contains the fixes [here](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4015549) is the patches that apply to Windows 7

> - April, 2017 Security Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB4015549)
> - April, 2017 Security Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows 7 (KB4015549)

May 2017: [KB4019264](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4019264)

Comment: [Fix Windows Update errors (0x80070020)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10164/fix-windows-update-errors)